# Merge two tables together and overwrite exisiting values with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, union

I try to merge two tables together and want to get a single table with SQL. My main problem is to overwrite existing values, because in the 2nd table `(deltaTable)` are some new revision rows, that have the same ID as in the first table `(rootTable)`.

Example:

**1) rootTable**

```
ID | REV | NAME
 1 |   0 | Part 1
 2 |   0 | Part 2
 3 |   0 | Part 3
 4 |   0 | Part 4
 5 |   0 | Part 5
```

**2) deltaTable**

```
ID | REV | NAME
 2 |   1 | Part 2
 4 |   2 | New Part 4
```

**I want to have the following result:**

```
ID | REV | NAME
 1 |   0 | Part 1
 2 |   1 | Part 2
 3 |   0 | Part 3
 4 |   2 | New Part 4
 5 |   0 | Part 5
```

Can anyone help me or give me an hint how to manage the SQL code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use an UPDATE query:

```
update
  rootTable r inner join deltaTable d
  on r.id = d.id
set
  r.REV = d.REV,
  r.NAME = d.NAME
```

Please see it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90cd3/1).
As Hogan suggested, we could add something like `where d.rev>r.rev` since it should help giving better performances.

An alternative query, if you defined ID as a primary key, is:

```
insert into rootTable (ID, REV, NAME)
select * from deltaTable
on duplicate key update
  REV=values(REV), NAME=values(NAME);
```

(this will update existing records, and add new ones).

Please see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7923f/1).

Comment: maybe you want a `WHERE  r.REV <> d.REV OR r.NAME <> d.NAME` to reduce locking of rows that are not changing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `And`ed? `WHERE r.REV <> d.REV AND r.NAME <> d.NAME` @Hogan

Comment: @1000111 of course not -- you want to change the two columns if one of the two columns is different.

Comment: Sorry. Just skimmed over the question. Head's dull! should have perused. @Hogan

Comment: @Hogan yes thank you, I've updated the answer, I think we could just use d.rev>r.rev but this depends on the context. An index on rev should help also.

Comment: @fthiella agreed index would be very helpful if this is not a single use ad-hoc query.

Comment: Ah, cool, thank you very much! Now it works! What do I have to do, if I just want to have the Selection of the result (instead of the INSERT-command)?